# unable to visualise embedded OLE (spreadsheet) in libre Draw

Tags: libreoffice

I am unable to view an embedded spreadsheet in draw.The OLE is very much there since when I click on where its supposed to be it pops up and i can edit it.But it seems to be hidden once i click elsewhere on the page.While exporting as a pdf, the space where the OLE should have been is blank on the page.how can i unmask this spreadsheet?